# What do you mean by CPU-GPU configuration in deep learning using tensorflow (keras)?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

I am a beginner in Deep Learning using Python.
I am doing a Assignment in my 2nd semester.

```
#max: 1 gpu, 56 cpu
config = tf.ConfigProto( device_count = {'GPU': 0 , 'CPU': 56} )
sess = tf.Session(config=config) 
keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

What do these above lines of code mean??

Comment: well, it simply tells the tensorflow backend that it cannot use any GPU (0), but can use up to 56 CPU cores for running tasks.

Comment: Thank you Derlin:-)